# Problem in class to identify the gender of a word. AttributeError: 'Gender' object has no attribute 'male'

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function, class

I would like to identify if a variable1 is masculine or feminine. I would like to use the class which is called from the condition (as you can see in my code).

I get the error:

```
     if variable1 == gender.male:
AttributeError: 'Gender' object has no attribute 'male'
```

but I probably misspelled the class. I'm not very experienced with classes. I need the class to be a grammar rules container with male.startswith("o") and female.startswith("a"). Next I call the rules of the class with a condition, to check if variable1 is gender.male or gender.female.

**IMPORTANT:** I need to invoke the condition so:
`if variable1 == gender.male` (or similar)

So variable1 must match gender.male, NOT the other way around (`if gender.male: print(variable1`)

Can you show me how, from my code example, i can get the `"Pedro is male"` output? (or `"Lola is Female"` in case I change the content of variable1 with Lola). Thank you all!

```
variable1 = "Pedro"

class Gender:
    def __eq__(self, male, female):
        x= male.startswith("o")
        y= female.startswith("a")
        return x,y

gender = Gender()


if variable1 == gender.male:
    print(variable1, " is male")
else:
    print(variable1, " is female")
```

Thank you all!

Comment: You're comparing apples and firetrucks. "variable1" is holding a String value. class Gender has no defined attributes, let alone one called 'male'.  It has a routine called __eq__, which ought to compare two Genders and return an integer, but it tests its arguments and returns a pair. And finally, "startswith" is no use if you're expecting to compare the last letter.  It's difficult to know how to salvage this.  ...

Comment: At the very least, I'd suggest a 'class Person', that has at least two attributes, a name and a Gender.  Gender needs a single attribute, with value male or female, with __eq__ comparing that attribute.  And finallly, the Person's Gender is assigned by default based on the last character ('endswith') of the name.

Comment: @ArfurNarf You're kind. Could you show me an answer with a code example please? I will be very happy to accept your answer in case it helps. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem in class to identify the gender of a word. AttributeError: 'Gender' object has no attribute 'male'

I believe the error is self-explanitory: Your 'Gender' object (specifically your instance 'gender') has no male attribute.

> I would like to identify if a string is masculine or feminine.

From your example you seem know how to use if statements to determine if a string is *masculine* or *feminine* however I think that you ment to use the [`endswith`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-endswith-method/) function instead of the `startswith` to detect this property by comparing the last character of your string to a custom value:

```py
variable1 = "Pedro"

if variable1.endswith("o"):
    print(variable1, "is male")
elif variable1.endswith("a"):
    print(variable1, "is female")
```

> I would like to use the class which is called from the condition. But I probably misspelled the class. I'm not very experienced with classes.

You didn't misspelled the class, instead two other things happened:

1. You used the [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) method while trying to initialize your class attributes, this method is used to compare instances but in your code you only make use of one  instance `gender`. To initialize your class attributes without comparing instances (each instance will be *unique*) you should use the [`__init__`](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-oop/python-__init__/) method instead.
2. You tried to define you class attributes as `x = value` instead you need to reference the current instance with the keyword [`self`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/self-in-python-class/) as in `self.x = value`. Also, note that you don't need to return the values from the internal function `init`.

```py
class Gender:
    def __init__(self, variable):
        self.male = variable.endswith("o")
        self.female = variable.endswith("a")
```

> Can you show me how, from my code example, i can get the "Pedro is male" output? (or "Lola is Female" in case I change the content of variable1 with Lola). Thanks

```py
variable1 = "Pedro"

class Gender:
    def __init__(self, variable):
        self.male = variable.endswith("o")
        self.female = variable.endswith("a")

gender = Gender(variable1)

if gender.male:
    print(variable1, "is male")
elif gender.female:
    print(variable1, "is female")
```

However in my experience this would be a more object-oriented way of using [classes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-classes-and-objects/) and thinking about the problem:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.male = name.endswith("o")
        self.female = name.endswith("a")
    
    def printPersonGender(self):
        if self.male:
            print(self.name, "is male")
        elif self.female:
            print(self.name, "is female")
        else:
            print(self.name, "is unknown")

firstPerson = Person("Pedro")
firstPerson.printPersonGender()

secondPerson = Person("Lola")
secondPerson.printPersonGender()
```

EDIT: What you are asking for in your comment is conceptually wrong (it doesn't make sense to compare the string `variable1` with a class attribute. But if for some unknown reason you **need** that comparison `variable1 == gender.male` this could be a solution to your problem:

```py
variable1 = "Lola"

class Gender:
    def __init__(self, variable):
        if variable.endswith("o"):
            self.male = variable
        else:
            self.male = None

gender = Gender(variable1)

if variable1 == gender.male:
    print(variable1, "is male")
else:
    print(variable1, "is female")
```

Again, I need to stress that this is a **bad** way of doing things but it may be closer to what you need.

EDIT2:

```py
variable1 = "Lola"

class Gender:
    def __init__(self, variable):
        if variable.endswith("o"):
            self.male = variable
            self.female = None
            
        if variable.endswith("a"):
            self.female = variable
            self.male = None

gender = Gender(variable1)

if variable1 == gender.male:
    print(variable1, "is male")

if variable1 == gender.female:
    print(variable1, "is female")
```

Comment: You've come very close to what I'm looking for. If you allow, I would like to study your code a bit and see if I can apply it to my script (already made). I'll get back to you later or tomorrow. For now I vote for your answer and thank you. See you soon

Comment: In the first solution of your answer, I would need the condition to be something like this: if variable1 == gender.male: . I'm trying to edit, but I can't. So variable1 must match gender.male, not the other way around (if gender.male: print(variable1). 
It must revolve all around variable1 in the condition. Can you help me in this direction please? I will gladly accept your answer in case it helps. Thank you

Comment: Yes, I know it's bad, you're right. In your third solution though, variable.endswith("a") is missing which matches female. In the class, I tried adding if variable.endswith("a"): self.female = variable, and then next also adding if variable1 == gender.female: print(variable1, "is Female"), but it doesn't work. Could you add me also female please? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `person object` that has `name` and `gender` as their `class variables`. You can then create a function that determines the gender given that a name is provided as input:

```
def identify_gender(name):
    if name.lower().endswith('o'):
        return "Male"
    elif name.lower().endswith('a'):
        return "Female"
    else:
        return "Undefined"

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.gender = identify_gender(self.name)

variable1 = "Pedro"
person_obj = Person(variable1)

print("{} is a {}".format(person_obj.name, person_obj.gender))
```

The console outputs:

```
Pedro is a Male
```

Note that `lower()` is used to be more general in the case that all the letters capitalized.

Comment: I needed something similar to my code. Your code is too different from mine. Could you also show me a solution similar to my code please? I need to maintain a similar structure to my code. I will gladly accept your answer in case it helps. Thanks

Comment: With your code example, I'm not entirely sure how you want to achieve this. The `__eq__` method is used to compare two objects together that are of the same class and see if they're equal. You want to compare a string to the gender object which are of different classes.

Comment: I need the class not to be Person, but to be Gender, so I would like to put male.startswith("o") and female.startswith("a") in the class. I would like the class to be just a container for the grammar rules. Next i call the class rules with a condition, to check if variable1 is gender.male or gender.female....like this (or similar): if variable1 == gender.male

Comment: I upvoted your answer with pleasure, even if I need more

Comment: @EvangelosDellas *I needed something similar to my code. Your code is too different from mine.*.  No offense meant, but your code has severe conceptual isseues.  You’re asking for help about it and people are trying to help you.  Requiring that they do so by following in your footsteps isn’t productive if your approach is flawed.  applies to any of us, even experienced programmers, who  just approached a problem incorrectly.  Mind you, a lot of people here also tend to, wrongly, say “dont do this!” when they dislike a particular approach for no real reason.  So you have  to excercise judgment.